# Laravel - Group multiple where clause as orWhere

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to append multiple `where` clause and make them `orWhere` clause?

This is what I mean:

```
public function call() 
{
    $pageTypes = ["page_user", "guest_user" ...etc];
    $appendQuery = [];

    // in here, the query is always where making the sql query "page_type LIKE %page_user% and page_type LIKE %guest_user%"
    // my written mysql query here might be written wrong but I hope you get the idea.
    // I want to change the subsequent query to orWhere
    foreach ($pageTypes as $i => $pageType) {
        array_push($appendQuery, function ($query) use ($pageType) {
            return $this->addPageTypeQuery($query, $pageType);
        });
    }

}

public function addPageTypeQuery($query, $pageType)
{
    return $query->where('page_type', 'LIKE', $pageType);
}
```

Though I can manually create a function with query where・orWhere, but if there is a laravel/php way to do this, that would help.

**Note** I am unable to change the contents of `addPageTypeQuery` function. I know I can add an input parameter inside then create an `ifelse/switch` statement to determine what the desired return data but I cannot do so since my PM will not allow it.

**Extra note** I forgot I can use whereIn but currently there is no whereIn function in the current repository.php file I am working and I cannot add/edit functions because of PM. I might create my own function of whereIn clause <strike>or hack the appenedQuery and manually change the where to orWhere (Bad practice)</strike> Too complicated. Will create a `whereIn` instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do, but can't you do it with `whereIn`? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

Comment: Oh yean I forgot `whereIn`. I think whereIn might work. But there is no current `whereIn` function in the repository that I am using. I am unable to add/edit in the repo file so I might need to create my own function for this.

Comment: So you can't change `addPageTypeQuery` method, but you can change `call` as you need?

Comment: yes. `call` is the function that I am working on

Comment: Can you avoid using `addPageTypeQuery` method and write your code like this: 
`$query->whereIn('page_type', $pageTypes)`

Comment: I could create but not in current repository file (very strict rule). Still asking for permission to be allowed to write in repository file. If not, then I will need to create it somewhere instead.

Answer (score 0):

`orWhere()` just uses `where()` in the background so you should be able to do it. The signature for the `where` method is

```php
public function where($column, $operator = null, $value = null, $boolean = 'and')
{
    ...
}
```

`orWhere` is pretty similar

```php
public function orWhere($column, $operator = null, $value = null)
{
    ...
    return $this->where($column, $operator, $value, 'or');
}
```

---

With this in mind, I think you only need a way to pass an extra argument to your `addPageTypeQuery` method.

```php
public function addPageTypeQuery($query, $pageType, $boolean = 'and')
{
    return $query->where('page_type', 'LIKE', $pageType, $boolean);
}
```

```
foreach ($pageTypes as $i => $pageType) {
    array_push($appendQuery, function ($query) use ($pageType) {
        if (/* should be an OR query */) {
            return $this->addPageTypeQuery($query, $pageType, 'or');
        }

        return $this->addPageTypeQuery($query, $pageType);
    });
}
```

Comment: I am unable to add a new parameter to the function though, as stated in my note. However if I do add a parameter inside, I was thinking of doing if/else statement. Good to know that I can add a parameter inside the where part.